# selecting all orders for last 30 days, and counting how many per day

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to select **all orders for last 30 days** from one customer, so I need to have customer_id = "$customer_id" and **count how many orders I have per each day** for that one customer.

I need to end up with array like this

```
Array ( 
  [1] => Array (
                 [orders] => 41
                 [date] => 2011-06-13 17:43:50 
               )
  [2] => Array (
                 [orders] => 11
                 [date] => 2011-07-13 17:43:50  
               )
  [4] => Array (
                 [orders] => 2
                 [date] => 2011-12-13 17:43:50  
               )

  and so on... for 30 days, if some day I dont have any orders, I dont need array or [orders] = 0 ...

}
```

I have table named "orders" with id, customer_id and date field.

I found this questions [SQL query for Calculating Total No. of Orders per Day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133109/sql-query-for-calculating-total-no-of-orders-per-day) but its not helping me, or I dont understand it very well, btw I am beginner. Thanks!

p.s. what I managed to do, is to select all orders for last 30 days.

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id=" . $customer['id'] . " AND date > ADDDATE(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)")->result_array();
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you need to select all orders, or just the number of orders for each day?

Comment: Total number of orders per date, like visitors per day, I need to create chart at the end usign flot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use MySQL [EXTRACT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function to fetch *day* from your *date field* and then group by results according to this. I haven't try it but the following query should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS orders, date_field
FROM your_table
WHERE customer_id=$my_cusotmer
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_field)
```

Comment: thanks!, when I put it like this its working I think "SELECT COUNT( * ) AS orders, date FROM orders WHERE customer_id =41 AND date > ADDDATE( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -30 DAY ) GROUP BY EXTRACT( DAY FROM date )"

Comment: Use bacticks around date since it is a reserved keyword for most of the RDBMSs including MySQL.