# Selecting and counting all orders of the past 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to get all orders of the past 30 days and return the total and how many orders there were. If a day has no orders I still want a row in my result (obviously with count and total == 0).

Is there a way to do this?

There are a lot of questions asking this without the requirement of always getting 30 rows. However, I can't comment on them because my reputation is too low.

For example:
[selecting all orders for last 30 days, and counting how many per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559428/selecting-all-orders-for-last-30-days-and-counting-how-many-per-day)

Comment: How is your database structured?

Comment: Do you really need to do this? Can't the code processing the results just know it's a zero if it isn't in the SQL?

Comment: If you really want to do all of this in the SQL, this sounds like a job for a stored procedure to me. The sproc would create a temp table where you insert 30 records (1 for each day), then come back and update order totals for each of those days. That would get you your desired output of always having 30 days in your result set

Comment: I have an order table which contains an ID, order time, and the price (and some customer data, but I don't think this is relevant).

Comment: I'd prefer to do it with an SQL query. I could add the missing arrays in PHP before passing it to the template, but that sounds like more work than it should be...

Comment: do you need all orders (every row) or grouped by day ?

Comment: Grouped by day. So I get: day n -> x orders, y total amount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Days generator is taken from here [generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)

another job is simple left join to grouped orders

(change with your table and column names in left join subquery)

```
select a.Date, pr.orders_count, pr.price
from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
left join (select order_time, count(*) as orders_count, sum(price) as price from orders group by order_time) pr
on a.Date = pr.order_time
where  a.Date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY 
order by a.Date desc
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: A word of warning about using NOW() here.  NOW() returns the  current time AND date, for example 2017-03-24 1330.  NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY would return 2017-02-22 1330.  If your Order Dates include a Time component, wittingly or unwittingly, then any Order from that Date with an earlier Time would be excluded.  If you wish to avoid NOW()'s Time component, try using CURDATE() instead.  If there is a Time component in your Order Dates, try using DATE().  e.g. WHERE DATE( a.Date ) >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY

Comment: Good catch! Will update the code to use `CURDATE()` after the weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a calendar table or date dimension for this.

```
select td.db_date, count(o.OrderId) as Orders
from time_dimension td
  left join Orders o
    on date(o.OrderDate) = db_date
where td.db_date >= date(adddate(curdate(), interval -30 day))
  and td.db_date <= date(curdate())
group by td.db_date
```

MySQl Calendar table reference

- [MYSQL: Generate Calendar Table - bryhal (gist)](https://gist.github.com/bryhal/4129042)
- [Calendar Tables: An Invaluable Database Tool - Brian Showalter](https://www.brianshowalter.com/blog/calendar_tables)

Comment: Very interesting read! I like how readable the query becomes when you've got that calendar table. However, I kind of dislike that one has to create an entire new table for this (seemingly simple) problem.

Comment: @DennisHein I'm glad you found it interesting! I understand your hesitance concerning creating a table to facilitate queries. I wish I had a good reference that bench-marked the performance of queries using various sized date ranges and compared different approaches, e.g. Calendar table vs stacked values (accepted answer). The accepted answer is very fast, especially for a 30 day window, I'm sure any difference at that range wouldn't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator for dates from [Get a list of dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510012/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

After you can use outter join with your order table.

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
SELECT dateDuringPeriod, SUM( orderValue ), COUNT( orderID )
FROM
(
    SELECT dateDuringPeriod,
           IFNULL( orderID, 0 ) orderID,
           IFNULL( orderValue, 0 ) orderValue
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL singles + tens DAY) dateDuringPeriod
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT 0 singles
            UNION ALL SELECT -1
            UNION ALL SELECT -2
            UNION ALL SELECT -3
            UNION ALL SELECT -4
            UNION ALL SELECT -5
            UNION ALL SELECT -6
            UNION ALL SELECT -7
            UNION ALL SELECT -8
            UNION ALL SELECT -9
        ) singles JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 0 tens
            UNION ALL SELECT -10
            UNION ALL SELECT -20
        ) tens
    ) datesDuringPeriod LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT orderID,
               DATE( orderDate ) orderDate,
               orderValue
        FROM tblOrders
    ) ordersWithoutTimes
ON datesDuringPeriod.dateDuringPeriod = ordersWithoutTimes.orderDate
) tblOrderSummary
GROUP BY dateDuringPeriod
ORDER BY dateDuringPeriod;
```

I have created a sample table with sample data and found this code to be effective.

Comment: Original answer updated to MySQL syntax (sorry - programming with a cold and feeling woozier than I thought).  Please feel free to ask any questions you might have.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time. Your answer sadly doesn't completely work. If there is a day without orders the corresponding row will be missing.

Comment: Oops!  My bad.  I'll get stuck into the problem now.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but want to let you know that Oto Shavadze has posted a working solution. Just in case you want to save some time :)

Comment: Actually, I'm mainly interested in using this as a stimulating programming exercise and in helping out.  It's great if I get the points, but I'm mainly interested in any feedback that I get.

Comment: Answer updated.  It now produces the full list.  Once again, I would appreciate any comments offered.

Comment: Answer updated to be more in line with my comment on Oto Shavadze's answer.  Also, layout slightly improved.